# Launch Web Browser After Tomcat Startups in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, browser, tomcat

In my old Eclipse setup, I used to have a web browser launch whenever Eclipse builds my project and Tomcat finishes starting up.  Now, on my new computer, I've lost that setting.

I was able to change which browser would be the default browser for Eclipse (Windows > Preference > General > Web Browser ).  However, now after it says "INFO: Server startup in xxxxxxx ms", I have to manually open my browser and go to "http://localhost:8080/webapp_name".

Does anyone know how to make Eclipse automatically launch the browser after Tomcat finishes starting up?  It's very useful particular for builds that takes minutes.

Comment: That's normally to be done by *Run As > Run on Server* option. Did you choose that option to launch the project in the configured browser?

Answer (score 2):

Do the reverse of this one:
[how to stop Eclipse browser from displaying web page upon restarting tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752556/how-to-stop-eclipse-browser-from-displaying-web-page-upon-restarting-tomcat)

I just turned off my auto browser open by having internet explorer in that setting,  try with default for ti to open auto again.