# how to stop Eclipse browser from displaying web page upon restarting tomcat?

Tags: eclipse, browser, window

The old eclipse bug which is very annoying for me.

The situation: I stop tomcat server => run web application again => get browser window. The problem is that browser window is displayed earlier before the redeployment process finishes itself, so whenever I try to close the browser window(since I prefer to open web application in standard browser since the native is laggy and slow)  in that short interval, my Eclipse hangs with error message window:

Script Error: An error has occurred in the script on this page

Line: 1

Char: 1

Error: Unspecified error

URL: about:blank

Do you want to continue running scripts on this page?

Yes No

The problem is that application hangs plus the window is inactive and I can't make this window active.

To fix this I have to end the process and shutdown tomcat manually on .bat. This is very annoying when you repeat this around ten times a day.

It doesnt happen if I wait till the application is completely redeployed, but I have habit of working fast, so eventually I close the window again before redeployment.

The help could be either in:

1. how to forbid eclipse showing browser window tab when web application is redeployed?
2. or how to fix this error?

Thank You guys,

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Aubergine, I've had the same experience as you.  Here's one answer for selecting the external browser:

You can choose another browser as your default by changing preferences in Eclipse.  Select Window > Preferences > General > Web Browser.  Now choose the option "Use External Web Browser", and check the checkbox for the browser you use in the box below[image].

Comment: @Vile the solution suggested by MAbraham1 works flawlessy and prevents Eclipse to hang up. Please mark it as solution.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Neon, and I followed the above, but the browser does not open. I guess it's because I'm not setting the startup URL anywhere. Where do I set that?

Comment: @Ray, which browser are you using?  What URL were you expecting to see when starting your web app?  Check under Preferences -> General -> Web Browser (above image).  Eclipse bug reports for Neon include some SWT browser references (https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/development/readme_eclipse_4.6.html#mozTocId69222), but my hunch is yours is a configuration issue.  I would also check the Eclipse logs (https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_can_I_find_that_elusive_.log_file).  Happy New Year!

Comment: @MAbraham1 I'm using Chrome. But I would assume the URL would be something like http://localhost:9999 but where do I get the port number? When I work with visual studio, it gives me the port number in the properties page when the project is generated.

Comment: @Ray, be sure that the Servers project is open, then open the Servers tab and right-click on your server (i.e., Tomcat).  The Properties pane should appear.  If you click 'Monitoring', you can see the server port, which generally is 80 for http/1.1, whereas https is 443.